# Multiple condition foreach JSON booking system

Tags: javascript, json, mobile, hybrid

I want to prevent user from adding booking to a slot that is already booked by another user:

This is the JSON structure:

```
  "id": 1,
  "date": "2016-01-01T00:00:00",
  "time": 1,
  "userid": "21",
  "doctorid": "1"
```

I got mixed up in the condition algorithm. This is my condition for now. This will iterate each id in json.

```
for(var index = 0;index < bookingData.totalRows;index++)
{
  var boolBookDateExist = false;
  var boolBookTimeExist = false;
  var boolBookDoctorExist = false;

  if(bookingDetails.date.localeCompare(moment(new Date(bookingData.data[index].date)).format("YYYY-MM-DD")) != 0)
  {
     boolBookDateExist = true;
  }
  if(bookingDetails.time.localeCompare(bookingData.data[index].time) != 0)
  {
    boolBookTimeExist = true;
  }
  if(bookingDetails.doctorid.localeCompare(bookingData.data[index].doctorid) != 0)
  {
    boolBookDoctorExist = true;
  }
  if(boolBookDateExist && boolBookTimeExist && boolBookDoctorExist)
  {

  }
  else
  {

  }
}
```

bookingDetails is the data trying to be inserted into database. 
(Going to book slot)

bookingData is the data from database existed. (Already booked slot)

I dont know how to verify either the slot has been booked or not with json.

Comment: What is the time slot like? In your code, you are comparing date,  then  time as a number instead of  a range.

Comment: @Awakening Byte, I already simplified time range to timeid to ease things up.